# command line web browsing

Tags: windows, http, ubuntu

Is there a way to perform http commands GET/PUT/SET whatever via a command line in ubuntu or windows xp?  Preferably without installing 3rd party products.  Being that http is text based I thought it would be alot easier to run in the cmd line.

I've been able to get what I want out of GET in ubuntu in bash via

```
$wget google.com
$cat index.html
```

This is kinda clunky.  It would be nice to pipe the output or something, but even that isn't straight forward.  C programs are fine too.  I'm trying to do something like what we get with Fiddler, but more basic.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Download a file for scripting purposes, or browse?

Comment: If you add `-O -` you won't need to cat it. And curl is a more full-featured version of wget. last, technically you can just telnet or netcat on port 80 and type the commands yourself

Comment: P.S. If you just want to browse, there are several options. My personal favorite is elinks but links, lynx, and w3m are all good

Comment: This is just for some one off tests.  Throw away stuff.  Didn't know if I had to code it or could get away with a command line command so I posted it on Stack where people know both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
telnet google.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: google.com
```

You have to hit return twice after the Host line.  It doesn't get any more basic.

Answer (score 5):

If you are familiar with HTTP use `telnet`.

If you are looking for a *browser* take a look for [Links](http://links.twibright.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Although it requires a 3rd party tool, these days I use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).  The [-X option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X) allows me to specify the HTTP verb.  Windows has a few bash clients that allow you to run curl including [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

### Sample Execution

`$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{value: "600"}' http://localhost:8888/my/endpoint`